# blank comment entry with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to add ability to add comments to projects within a "todo" type app and have run into a problem.

I've created a project with comments before and never run into this problem, but basically rails is drawing an empty comment on the project page.

I've tried a few if statements without any luck, does anyone see my problem ?

```
<% @project.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="commentBlock"><strong><%= comment.posted_by %>  says:</strong>
    <%=raw comment.comment %>
    <small><i class="icon-remove"></i> <%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.project, comment],:confirm => 'Are you sure?',:method => :delete %></small></div>
<% end %>

<h3>Leave a comment</h3>

<%= form_for([@project, @project.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :posted_by, :value => current_user.username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :comment, :class => "tinymce" %><%= tinymce %>
  </div>
  <p><%= f.submit :class => 'btn' %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I should mention, everything works, 

I'm just left with an empty comment if there aren't any ( or even if there are )

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because of TinyMCE. what it the generated HTML ?

Comment: tiny MCE is working, and was added after this bug was already present :P ( not related )

html output is as it should be, except empty

Comment: What are the params received when you post a new comment?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that ?

Comment: I guess its because of the `@project.comments.build` which adds an empty comment to the collection. Try `Comment.new`.

Comment: Add `raiser params` to your corresponding action that creates a new comment and post the output of this hash

Comment: Does it work if you remove the class `tinymce` of this text_area ?

Comment: the bug persists, it's not related to tinymce at all.

I have tinymce working flawlessly throughout my project.

Comment: It also persists if I remove the form from the page all together, the loop to show existing comments always shows that html for the comment, just once, even if there isn't one.. on any project_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer was an error in my controller for Projects, referenced @comment like so:**

```
@comment = @project.comments.build(params[:comment]) by accident!!
```

**Changed to:**

```
@comment = @project.comments
```

And all works as it should :P 
thanks for your help, bad "end of the day" error right there :P